# Reading Data from SQLite Database to a new Activity - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating an android app that has basically 6 inputs (2 from spinners and the rest textviews) and am using an SQLite Database. I have got as far as when the user clicks on a "start button" the data is saved successfully to the database and also displays on the same activity.

The problem that i am asking help for is.. i want to display the saved data, not on the same activity(screen) in which the data is being saved but on a different activity. So, for instance everything is working in terms of storing and displaying the data on screen 1, but how do i retrieve the data again on screen 2?

Here is the code that i have to save the data (DataBaseHelper):

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +"  (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,LINETYPE TEXT,PACKAGETYPE TEXT,QUANTITY TEXT,DURATION TEXT,STARTTIME TEXT,ENDTIME TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String linetype, String packagetype, String quantity, String duration, String starttime, String endtime) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,linetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,packagetype);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,quantity);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,duration);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,starttime);
    contentValues.put(COL_7,endtime);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return res;
}
```

And some code from the activity:

```
//INSERT DATA TO DATABASE
            boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(
                    spinnerSelection,
                    spinnerSelection2,
                    q,
                    d,
                    formattedtime,
                    endtimecalc);

            if(isInserted == true)
                Toast.makeText(screen2.this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(screen2.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                //show messages
                showMessage("Error", "Nothing Found");
                return;
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()) {
                buffer.append("ID: " + res.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("LineType: " + res.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("PackageType: " + res.getString(2)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Quantity: " + res.getString(3)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Duration: " + res.getString(4)+"\n");
                buffer.append("StartTime: " + res.getString(5)+"\n");
                buffer.append("EndTime: " + res.getString(6)+"\n\n");
            }

            //SHOW ALL DATA
            showMessage("Data", buffer.toString());


        }
    });
}

public void showMessage(String title,String Message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Message);
    builder.show();
}
```

So, i now need to display the same information which is being stored from this activity into a new one.

Anyone any thoughts?

ERROR STACK TRACE:

> 10-05 15:54:58.072 5958-5958/com.example.t_fdonnelly.pharmatest E/AndroidRuntime: 
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.example.t_fdonnelly.pharmatest, PID: 5958
>                                                                                     android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 13 requested, with a size of 13
>                                                                                         at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
>                                                                                         at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
>                                                                                         at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
>                                                                                         at com.example.t_fdonnelly.tracker.screen2$4.onClick(screen2.java:196)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5653)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22509)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6144)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

UPDATED CODE:

```
 Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                //show messages
                showMessage("Error", "Nothing Found");
                return;
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String getid = res.getString(0);
            String getlt = res.getString(1);
            String getpt = res.getString(2);
            String getqty = res.getString(3);
            String getdur = res.getString(4);
            String getst = res.getString(5);
            String getet = res.getString(6);


            if ( res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    buffer.append(getid);
                    buffer.append(getlt);
                    buffer.append(getpt);
                    buffer.append(getqty);
                    buffer.append(getdur);
                    buffer.append(getst);
                    buffer.append(getet);
                } while (res.moveToNext());
            }


            Intent TransferData = new Intent(getBaseContext(), screen4.class);
            TransferData.putExtra("ID", getid);
            TransferData.putExtra("LineType", getlt);
            TransferData.putExtra("PackageType", getpt);
            TransferData.putExtra("Quantity", getqty);
            TransferData.putExtra("Duration", getdur);
            TransferData.putExtra("Starttime",getst);
            TransferData.putExtra("endtime", getet);

            startActivity(TransferData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: by passing unique row `ID` to the second activity

Comment: Hi @pskink... would you be able to give me some sample code for this?

Comment: see `SQLiteDatabase#insert` return value

Comment: Sorry not sure what this means?

Comment: what does `insert` method return?

Comment: Im trying to read data from the database not insert data into it.

Comment: you dont insert any data? so where does it come from?

Comment: Okay so.. the data is being inserted(successfully) in the say Main Activity and everything is fine its saving the correct data to the database. my question is how do i retrieve data from the database in a new activity

Answer (score 1):

When you starting new activity via Intent you can put your strings as extras

```
String id = res.getString(0);
String lineType = res.getString(1);
//rest of cursor logic
sb.append("ID: ").append(id).append("\n");
sb.append("LineType: ").append(lineType).append("\n");
//rest of StringBuffer logic
Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    newActivity.putExtra("ID", id);
    newActivity.putExtra("LineType", lineType);
    startActivity(newActivity);
```

In new activity call getIntent() method and retrieve them from it

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");
```

Comment: Sounds good! how to i point the intent so that it opens up the next activity as well?

Comment: I edited my anwer for better example. You should use special constructor agrumens - your context (current activity instance e.g.) and Class off activity you want to start.

Comment: Thankyou! it seems that it is not recognising the name of the activity i am trying to start and transfer the data to and its causing an error.. i will keep working at it

Comment: Hi i created the new intent with the .putextra for each of my inputs and then on the receiving activity i used the getintent methods to call the strings and then assigned the strings to the corresponding textviews. however, the intent is causing my app to crash still?

Comment: Can you show what your error stack trace is? There is several reasons that may cause your crash.

Comment: Yeah how i can i show you this as there is a character limit here? i could add it on to my initial post

Comment: Ok I got it. Seems like you're trying to get data from your cursor when it already reached the end. The best for you is assign every res.getString() result to new String variable. Then add those variables to your StringBuffer and to Intent's extras.

Comment: when you say res.string "result" what does this mean? ps thanks for this lol

Comment: result - is smth, that function returns. In this case - some value of String type, stored in Cursor object.

Comment: Done that.. occur is still occuring i will upload my new code again have a look above.. also noticing each time the index requested number and size is increasing by 1

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**

get a unique key for your data in database table like...

```
public long insertData(String linetype, String packagetype, String quantity, String duration, String starttime, String endtime) {
     ......
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return result;
}
```

in calling activity.

```
long yourUniqueId = myDb.insertData(
                    spinnerSelection,
                    spinnerSelection2,
                    q,
                    d,
                    formattedtime,
                    endtimecalc);
```

**Second**

Pass this `yourUniqueId` with intent as `putLong...etc`. and get it in Second activity. and fetch the record of corresponding id. and show it.

add new method in database class as. and then call it in second activity with the previous unique_id.

```
public Cursor getAllData(long uid) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" where ID = "+uid,null);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks! each record that is created has an ID attached which is autoincrementin... im not quite sure on the third step. any sample code?